# "scrollHeight" not updated in "onscroll" event handler when using HtmlCtrl in an application but works correctly in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, onscroll, htmlcontrols

When sample below code loads in IE9, it works correctly, but when loads in an html control in an application, `scrollHeight` not updated in `onscroll` event handler when I change the `innerHTML` content in the handler, and therefore the alert not to be displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function f()
{
    var nBodyHeightOld = document.getElementById("div1").scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += '<div>It is a test!</div>';
    if (document.getElementById("div1").scrollHeight != nBodyHeightOld)
        alert('scrollHeight changed!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='div1' style='overflow:scroll; height:300px' onscroll="f()">
    <div style='height:400px'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuse the application use IE8. To force application use IE9 add meta tag to html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```